# MongoDB - Calculate field based on previous item's score

Tags: mongodb

I have encountered common query problem, that can often be found in finance / banking. However I find it rather difficult to do it in MongoDB using `aggregate()`

**Dataset:**

Each record in dataset represent one hour of candy-eating party. Hour with lower `hour` field happened earlier, than those with higher `hour` field.

**!!! Candies bought in earlier hour, can be eaten in later hour. !!!**

```json
{ "hour": 5, "candies_eaten": 14, "candies_bought": 0 } // Candies only eaten but not bought
{ "hour": 6, "candies_eaten": 97, "candies_bought": 8 }
{ "hour": 7, "candies_eaten": 23, "candies_bought": 0 }
{ "hour": 8, "candies_eaten": 0, "candies_bought": 16 }
{ "hour": 9, "candies_eaten": 3, "candies_bought": 1 } // 2 Candies eaten from previous hours, 1 from this hour
{ "hour": 10, "candies_eaten": 0, "candies_bought": 7 } // Candies only are bought, but not eaten!
```

**Desired output:**

```json
{"total_consumed_candies_that_were_bought_during_party": 11}
```

**My goal:**

I want to calculate how many candies have been purchased AND eaten during whole event.

Any ideas and insights warmly appreciated

Comment: Are you asking how to get the sum of both values from every document?

Comment: @Joe No, I edited question to be more clear and understandable.

Comment: It will be better if you can provide desired/sample output in the question.

Comment: @YongShun updated with desired output.